# Mediation Admob with Mobfox

Tags: android, admob, mobfox

This my code for showing Ads Mobfox.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ScrollView android:background="#d3d8c2" 
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:fillViewport="true" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<LinearLayout android:background="#ffffff"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
              android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- ads MobFox -->
<com.adsdk.sdk.banner.AdView android:layout_height="50dp" 
                             android:layout_width="300dp" 
                             adspaceWidth="320" 
                             adspaceHeight="50" 
                             adspaceStrict="true" 
                             publisherId="MY_PUBLISHER_ID" 
                             animation="true" 
                             location="true" 
                             request_url="http://my.mobfox.com/request.php" 
                             android:id="@+id/mobFoxView"/>

<!-- End ads Mobfox-->


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I configure mediation Admob in control panel MobFox, but I want to know is what is necessary to add the code "`xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`" ????

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use the `ads` namespace then you don't need to include it. It doesn't appear that you need it, some don't